# Listen for file events in PHP - sort of like select() works in UNIX

Tags: php, synchronization

I'm implementing a small chat system for my website.

The user sends a message to a PHP webpage... on the server this data is saved to a simple file. I read the file and WRITE some other message.

At this point I want the php web process to display the file change to the user.

So how do I listen for file change with PHP?

Comment: Personally, even for a small chat, I'd think that making it flat file based is somewhat unwieldy, with race conditions / lock contention. Also, what use is listening to changes unless you make a dedicated daemon instead of a webpage (which only has short lived bursts of live)? Afaik, easiest mimicking of chat functionality without the possibility of a push, is just a database, registering which message is the last the user saw, and poll with js to a page which will display all messages since last callback).

Comment: @Wrikken: so like many continuous ajax calls to a page that looks in a database? can you give me more details? I would like to avoid having the client open an http request every second or so... a long lived http request seems more logical...

Comment: Have a look at http://cometd.org/ or http://nodejs.org/ for push technologies.

Comment: nowadays, you might have other alternatives over HTTP, never used them personally, maybe @Gazler's suggestion would work. My main point was that a flat file storage is just asking for race conditions, overwrites, lost messages etc. Because HTTP is stateless, I've never even tried to implement chat functionality over HTTP.